# How can I access a list through a "for" loop if the list's name is stored in a variable I want to use?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, variables

Currently, I'm writing a program in Python v3.9.5 that plots data on a graph. It mostly works, but one of the features I'm trying to implement is the ability to choose your own color scheme. Previously, I did this by using one "if" statement for every single color scheme, but with 11 color schemes it takes up a lot of space. Here's the original code I used; from here on out, everything will be demonstrated on the "Red" color scheme.

```
if color == "Red":
        plotter.color(random.choice(Red))
```

And here's the list called "Red":

```
Red = ["IndianRed", "LightCoral", "Crimson", "Red", "FireBrick"]
```

Also, here's the modules I've imported:

```
import turtle
from turtle import *
import random
from math import floor
```

You're probably wondering why I imported stuff from turtle twice, and the answer is without that asterisk thing there the fill commands just break. I don't think I should remove it.

The function I'm writing takes five parameters: fill, color, square, x, y. "color" is the one I'd like to use to assign the color scheme inside the function; it is defined like so:

```
colorscheme = input("What color scheme would you like to use? ")
```

When we run the function, "colorscheme" is set as the parameter "color". I'm attempting to use a "for" loop to make the colors cycle through, so if the user plots data left to right, the points will be distinct, yet the method I tried doesn't work:

```
for i in color:
        plotter.color(i)
```

I think the issue is that Python is looking for a list named "color" and gets confused when it doesn't find one, even though "color" is the variable storing the list's name. Here is the error the shell gives me when I ask for the red color scheme and then try to plot a point:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/peytonhemann/Documents/Ridiculous Programs/Plotterv3.py", line 179, in <module>
    plotPoint(isfilled, colorscheme, graphsize, xvalue, yvalue)
  File "/Users/peytonhemann/Documents/Ridiculous Programs/Plotterv3.py", line 113, in plotPoint
    plotter.color(i)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 2217, in color
    pcolor = self._colorstr(pcolor)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 2697, in _colorstr
    return self.screen._colorstr(args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 1159, in _colorstr
    raise TurtleGraphicsError("bad color string: %s" % str(color))
turtle.TurtleGraphicsError: bad color string: R
```

How do I specify that I'm talking about the string stored inside "color", not "color" itself? Also, if I'm doing this completely wrong, is there a totally different way I can make the colors of one color scheme cycle through while using only one piece of code for every color scheme?

And, just a disclaimer, I'm still learning Python, so don't go hard on me in the comments if I did everything wrong or the answer's stupidly easy. This is also my first question here, so I might not have all the info you guys need. I'll reply to you with more info on my program if needed, though. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If your code won't work without the `from turtle import *` it means that you're referencing something from the turtle module without the `turtle.` prefix. The problem with `… import *` is that it may import things you're not aware of and can clobber your own variables with the same name — which makes debugging more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

In variable color you are passing "red" which in the loop will be understood as ["r","e","d"].

You should make a dictionary with the lists you want of the color.
Try this:

```
colors = {}
colors['red'] = ["IndianRed", "LightCoral", "Crimson", "Red", "FireBrick"]
```

And then

```
for i in colors[color]:
    plotter.color(i)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This does work...mostly. While the color selection worked perfectly, the color isn't changing; I plotted five points with the "Blue" color scheme and all were the same color; then I plotted some using "All" and it cycled quickly through every color until landing on the last. The code seems to select only the last color of each list after cycling through every one. Is there any way to fix this while still keeping the code you suggested?

Answer (score 0):

A good solution would to use a dictionary of names to values.

If you are sure you can't do the above, check again, if you are still sure, then you can do this:

```
if var_name in vars():
    my_var = vars()[var_name]
elif var_name in globals():
    my_var = globals()[var_name]
else:
    my_var = None
```